# How to display stars (1 to 5) from the value present in database

Tags: php, html, css

I have developed a page that shows the details of user achievements. I have a table that holds the level of the user.

Users( id, username, password, sum_score, level)

Based on the value present in level(i.e., from 0 to 5) I would like to like to display stars in the user page.

I tried something like :

```
$stars = "";
$s = 1;
while ($s<=$lvl['level']) {
    $stars.="&#9733;";
    $s++;
}

echo "$stars";
```

The above code produces star based on the level.(i.e., if the level is 1 it shows one star on the page). But I want to display 5 stars and fill the stars based on the level in the table. Can Someone help me out.

Comment: Welcome. Use a [for loop](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php) ?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong on your code. If `$lvl['level']` is getting the correct information from the database (i.e., 5) it should have been working properly. Can you tell us the return from `$lvl['level']`?

Comment: @Joska you want to display 5 stars no mater what and fill for example only one of them ?

Comment: @LucasArbex The code works to display the stars but i want to display all 5 stars and fill only the stars based on the level

Comment: @angel.bonev yes, if it level one i need to fill only one star

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using while, you can use a simple `for` loop in this case.

Assuming `$lvl['level']` is properly getting database's data (i.e., 5), you can loop until 5 compare it with `$lvl['level']` value, and display the star based on the if statement's result. Like so:

```
$stars = "";

for ($i = 1; $i <= 5; $i++) { 
    $i <= $lvl['level'] ? $stars .= "&#9733;" : $stars .= "&#9734;";
}

echo $stars;
```

Answer (score 0):

[str_repeat](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-repeat.php) is one option.

```
// stub for your record
$lvl = [
  'level' => 4
];

// render
$maxStars = 5;
$stars = (int)$lvl['level'];
$output = 
  str_repeat('&#9733;', $stars) . 
  str_repeat('&#9734;', $maxStars - $stars) .
  ' stars';

echo $output;
```

Output: https://3v4l.org/UFprQ

Answer (score 0):

If you add some classes and holders and add one if statement in the loop

```
<?php
$lvl = ["id" => 1, "level" => 4];
$stars = "";
for ($i = 1; $i < 6; $i++) {
    $stars .= '<span' . (($i <= $lvl["level"]) ? ' class="fill"' : '') . '>';            
    $stars .='&#9733;</span>';
}
echo '<div class="star"><div class="rating">' . $stars . '</div></div>';
```

Here is the snippet, HTML code is the output of the PHP:

```css
.star {
  width: 200px;
  position: relative;
  color: #bdbdbd;
}

.rating span {
  font-size: 30px;
  margin-left: -4px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.rating span:before {
  content: "\2605";
  position: absolute;
  color: gray;
}

.rating span.fill:before {
  content: "\2605";
  position: absolute;
  color: gold;
}
```

```html
<!-- this will be the output generated from php code used above !-->
<div class="star">
  <div class="rating"><span class="fill">★</span><span class="fill">★</span><span class="fill">★</span><span>★</span><span>★</span></div>
</div>
```